# OS Openspace with polygon layer through openlayers 3

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, ordnance-survey

I am trying to develop a web page displaying a base layer from Ordnance Survey openspace api and overlaying flood polygon data on to from geoserver. I understand that the CRS for OS is EPSG:27700 so what I have done is:

1) Loaded the flood data already in EPSG:27700 into Geoserver
2) Ensured that the Native CRS specified in GeoServer is EPSG:27700
3) Checked that the layer displays something in the "Layer Preview"
4) Created a basic webpage using OpenLayers3 utilising the handy JS code from Bill Chadwick (http://www.bdcc.co.uk/ol3/examples/os-openspace.html)

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script>

    var openSpaceOl3 = new OpenSpaceOl3('EB8FE9471221364EE0430B6CA40A6BDC', document.URL, OpenSpaceOl3.ALL_LAYERS);

  var layers = [  openSpaceOl3.getLayer(),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-6, 49, 2, 56], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:27700'),
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/FloodRisk/wms',
        params: {workspace:'Flood', layers: 'LowRisk', tiled: true},
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        projection: openSpaceOl3.getProjection();
      })
    })
    ];

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([0, 52.5], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:27700'),
      zoom: 8,
      projection: openSpaceOl3.getProjection();
    })
  });

</script>
```

The base layer displays correctly on its own, but when I add in the flood layer from GeoServer it doesn't work. It should work without too much problem if the projections of both layers are EPSG 27700 - right?!? 
I know that there are some more complicated examples overlaying OSM and OS tiles which require the proj4 transformations, but these should not be required if the transformation is the same - right? :-)

I have a feeling that some of the problem could be also due to the extents for the flood layer not being correct as when I take this line out the OS map does display and I can see calls to Geoserver in fiddler, but the tiles are not correct (presumably because the extents are missing).

Any ideas? - there could me multiple problems with the above code as I'm tying myself in knots trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot - I did need to include the proj4s.js library because open layers knows nothing about the 27700 projection. Once I did this and fixed a few other things it worked out.